# Help finding the artist

Tags: translation, characters, seal, calligraphy, transcription

I was given a painted scroll and would like some help in identifying the artist and finding out if it is of any value.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The artwork is signed with the name 「陸一飛」 (Mandarin Pinyin: **Lù Yīfeī**).

---

Calligraphy:

> 千里江陵一日還
>
> Second line of [Lǐ Bái](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Bai)'s [*Departing from Baidi in the Morning*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Departing_from_Baidi_in_the_Morning)
>
> 丙寅春日陸一飛畫
>
> *Painted in the spring of [bǐngyín](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%99%E5%AF%85) by Lù Yīfeī*

Seal:

> 一飛之Ｘ
>
> I can't read 「Ｘ」, but this probably says something like *Work of Yīfeī* or *Seal of Yīfeī*.